# Gunicorn does not find main module with docker

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up django using docker following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) but it fails with gunicorn not finding my main module.

Folder structure:

```
/project
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
  /web
    /static
    manage.py
    /django_project
      /apps_directories...
      /templates
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      wsgi.py
```

Web section of docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

Content of "django_project/wsgi.py":

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Error thrown when starting container:

```
[2016-11-01 16:39:48 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2016-11-01 16:39:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-11-01 16:39:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[2016-11-01 16:39:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-11-01 16:39:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2016-11-01 16:39:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-11-01 16:39:49 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2016-11-01 16:39:49 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'django_project'
```

Why doesn't it find the module?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be 100% sure without seeing your Dockerfile and the full setup but I think the issue is this section of the docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
```

In the repo for the tutorial you linked to the equivalent section is:

```
volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
```

This is because by using the [python:3.5-onbuild](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.5/onbuild/Dockerfile) image your code has aleady been baked in to the image and so does not need to be added as a volume.

I assume your reasoning for wanting to add the source code as a host volume mount is so that changes which you make are immediately reflected in the running image for development purposes. If this is the case then I think you should be able to achieve that by changing the problematic section to something like:

```
volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
```

Which would give you this for the whole web section:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

The only issue is that processes in the container run as root so you may have some issues with file permissions of any files which get created inside the container. If that becomes an issue then there are documented ways of solving it (which would depend on what you need to achieve) or you could always post another question here.